# Multiple ERC20 tokens in a DeFi platform

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, erc20

I'm building a DeFi application on Ethereum, and I would like to implement the `Deposit` function. Everything works fine between ETH and a ERC20 token that I built, but I would like to add some tokens like aToken for AAVE or cTokens for Compound that the user will receive after a `Deposit` call.

So the question is: is it possible to add a function in my smart contract to create multiple tokens without creating a smart contract for each of them? If not, I have to create a different contract for each token I want to add in my app or there is a best method to do it?

Comment: Why would you have to create an additional contract for each existing token and cannot use the existing tokens? Can you clarify your issue?

Comment: I would like to implement a deposit function like AAVE, which issues a particular token based on the token the user deposit. For example I deposit 1 ETH and the DeFi platform gives me 1 aETH which gains interests

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible. You can transfer the tokens to the user's address after the Compound Protocol mint operation. This can be made generic using the ERC-20 transfer interface. Be sure to account the amounts users are due and beware of the reentrancy vulnerability.